# Azure SSL Certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I am running into an issue when uploading my SSL certificate to Azure. I have a premium certificate from GoDaddy that has been running in IIS for the past year. As we are migrating to Azure, I exported it to a PFX, went to Azure to add it to my Web App, and received the following error message:

```
Failed to update web app settings
Failed to update web app settings for [APP_NAME]: The password is incorrect, or the certificate is not valid
```

I have tried the following:

- Ensure password is correct
- Export from IIS as pfx
- Export from MMC as pfx with full paths available

They all have the same results with the error message. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I got the certificate uploaded. The new Azure portal failed, so for a long shot, I tried the old portal which uploaded it without any issues.

Hopefully this helps someone else out in the future.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me days of hassle and a telling off! I have also tried creating a MySQL database in the new portal and it wouldn't work! I strongly advise using the old portal

Answer (score 11):

I had similar issues, and I managed to solve it by importing the existing PFX into my local cert store using powershell, and then exporting it again. The resulting PFX could then be imported into Azure. In the past I would use IIS to do this, but for some reason IIS can no longer export PFX files properly.

Here are the commands I used: (go to the cert store by doing 'cd cert:' in powershell.)

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\temp\a.pfx -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'xxxxx' -AsPlainText -Force) -Exportable

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My\0F84B10946C762AC4153E7A28DAB36C7108F92A0 -FilePath 'C:\temp\outfile.pfx' -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'xxxxx'  -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Comment: It works! You saved my day. Thank you

Comment: Saved my week. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice one! Thanks! ;)

Comment: Tried all that, but only get "Import-PfxCertificate : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))", PWD is correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

This is my case:
I used the tool OpenSSL for windows to generate pfx file by using command openssl pkcs12 -export -out domainname.pfx -inkey privatekey.key -in doamainname.crt.

Old azure portal is not available. When I upload certificate domainname.pfx to new Azure portal I got the following error: "The password is incorrect, or the certificate is not valid."
After struggling a lot I did the following:

1. Imported my domainname.pfx file to IIS locally.(Open IIS -> Select your machine name in the left menu -> Select Server certificates in the middle window -> On the right Action side select Import). It will ask pass for pfx file.
2. Export pfx certificate from IIS. (Select imported certificate in the middle window and then click Export on the right side of IIS window). It will ask you a new pass for a new pfx file and path where you want to save it.
3. After doing points 1,2 I uploaded newly created pfx file to Azure and Azure accepted it.

For me it's not still clear why local IIS was able import inital PFX file, but Azure doesn't, looks like a bug in Azure.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using the "https://portal.azure.com" trying the approach "App Service - "your app service" - ssl certificates - upload certificate"

When I tried to upload a certificate PFX file nothing happend, no error message, nothing.

The workaround I found was to re-generate the PFX file using openssl and this time add a short and simple password.

"openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem"

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while uploading pfx of a GoDaddy SSL certificate to Azure. I had exported the certificate to pfx from iis. This failed multiple times even though the password was correct.

Then I exported the certificate as pfx using the [tool from digiCert -](https://www.digicert.com/kb/util/pfx-certificate-management-utility-import-export-instructions.htm) https://www.digicert.com/kb/util/pfx-certificate-management-utility-import-export-instructions.htm

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I use 'Keystore Explorer' tool.