# Azure Websites - Masking Azure domain name

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In the next several months we will be going live with a web app ('MyApp') that is being hosted on Azure. We have purchased the MyApp.com domain and our Azure domain name is MyApp.azurewebsites.net.

We do not want our users to ever see the azure domain name in any form. We want them to see www.MyApp.com or www.MyApp.com/Sales/ViewSale etc.

I think I know how to map www.MyApp.com to MyApp.azurewebsites.net based on this [article](http://bretstateham.com/10-easy-steps-to-azure-web-site-custom-domains/). We won't be able to set this up for a while, so I'd like to know what the user will see in their browser URL when they go to www.MyApp.com. Will they see www.MyApp.com or MyApp.azurewebsites.net? And then what will they see as they navigate various pages in the app?

Comment: Let me know if I understand your question correctly - So you have an application currently running on myapp.azurewebsites.net and you also have procured a domain myapp.com but they are not linked as of today. Your questions as I understand are 1) What happens when somebody tries to access myapp.com in their browser today? and 2) What they will see when they type in myapp.com/some-page? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri - Not quite right. I do have an app running on Azure. I do have the MyApp.com domain name purchased. But they are not currently linked. I do not care what happens today if users go to MyApp.com. They won't see anything. My question pertains to what happens when MyApp.com is linked to my Azure website. I do not want them to see any Azure URLs in the browser. I only want them to see MyApp URLs.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. As mentioned by Martin Noreke in his answer, redirection is the only way. But you can make use of URLRewrite module for that purpose and redirect users to myapp.azurewebsites.net to myapp.com by including appropriate URL rewrite rule in your web.config file. Simply put, you can't prevent users from typing in myapp.azurewebsites.net and accessing your app but putting rewrite rule will automatically take the user to myapp.com. HTH.

Comment: I'm still not sure you understand. I can redirect. But when the use comes to my Azure website I do not want them to see the Azure URLs. I want them to see MyApp.com URLs. I do not want Azure URLs to appear anywhere.

Comment: Now I am confused :). What do you mean when you say `Azure URL`? Do you mean to find out what would happen when somebody types in `myapp.azurewebsites.net/some-page` instead of `myapp.com/some-page`?

Comment: I don't know how to make myself any clearer. Maybe take a look at the two responses I got. They know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the proper hosting level (the control panel will tell you, look for custom domains) and configuration, they can access it as www.myapp.com. You may need to provide your own SSL cert in order to configure it as well.

When it comes time to SSL, check out this post ([Azure SSL Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952874/azure-ssl-certificate/29955811)) that I made regarding uploading of SSL certs in the control panel. It will save you a headache.

The article you linked appears to have solid information based upon my recent experiences. One thing to note: It has screen shots from the old configuration panel, so some things may look different in the new one.

I haven't found a way to hide the myapp.azurewebsites.com method to access a page, other than maybe doing a redirect inside your code. However, until you have your DNS setup it might be nice to see things working under that domain to start.

Comment: Hmmm... The first answer says I won't see the azure names on any pages and your answer says I will. Someone is going to get voted down.

Comment: To provide some clarity, my site FirkinSense, https://firkinsense.azurewebsites.net/ and https://www.firkinsense.com go to the same server. The point I was trying to make was that even with DNS name resolution configured, the azurewebsites.net is controlled by Microsoft and can't be fully disabled. I hope this clears up that confusion.

Comment: Thanks Martin. This is exactly what I was asking about. When I go to your site, I do not see any Azure URLs in the browser URL display area.

Comment: You can also add a URL rewrite rule so that if anyone (human or bot) tries to access your azure domain name they get a Permanent Redirect pointing to your custom domain.

Answer (score 4):

Your azure website needs to be at least at the 'shared' level. This is the first tier of 'paid' azure website hosting. You do this under website > scale. 
app service plan pricing tier = shared.

then you would choose 'configure' and look for 'domains' and add your www.myapp.com domain.

Then you head out to your DNS manager and add a CNAME record that directs traffic from www.myapp.com to myapp.azurewebsites.com, OR you can lookup up the Virtual (public) IP of your azure website and update the A record in your DNS manager.

Either route, your visitors will see www.myapp.com/mypage,  www.myapp.com/mypage2, etc.