# ssl certificate bought from GoDaddy + Azure

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to upload my ssl certificate bought from GoDaddy to azure, but custom SSL is not supported in the Free or Shared tier. Do I really need to scale up my plan to Basic in order to install ssl in azure? Has anyone faced this before?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, it's crystal clear custom certificates are supported only in Basic and up - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#check-the-pricing-tier. You can still use `https://yourWebApp.azurewebsites.net` as freebie TLS in any SKU.

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952874/azure-ssl-certificate) case?

Comment: You are referencing a bug from 3 years ago, which has nothing do to with your scenario.

Comment: It's just not right for microsoft to force people to scale it up when my website does not need basic plan.

Comment: @pavilion In defence of Azure (or for that matter any cloud provider), not all workloads are suitable to run in cloud economically speaking. In fact, we ran our website in shared hosting for a very long time because it was quite expensive to run our website in Azure. Furthermore, we didn't really need the benefits (elasticity, scalability etc.) offered by cloud. I guess the point I am trying to make is that you probably don't have to host your application in Azure if you're not availing the full benefits offered by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is clear in that Custom Domains/SSL Certificates are not supported in the free tier.  Your choices are Shared, Standard, Basic, Premium, and Isolated--all of which are tiers you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

From your issue description, I believe it is Azure App Service WebApps. 
Yes. To use custom domains in Azure Web Apps, your web app's App Service plan must be a paid tier (Shared, Basic, Standard, or Premium). 
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app#prepare-the-app

Comment: No, that's nowhere near what he's asking.

Comment: Oh well, @evilSnobu would it be possible to transfer my domain bought from azure to godaddy? so I can use my ssl from godaddy's cpanel.

Comment: If you have purchased the domain from App Service Domain managed by Azure DNS and intending to transfer to Godaddy, I believe it is not possible.

Check the answers in the FAQ blog: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/08/08/faq-app-service-domain-preview-and-custom-domains/
Q:If I decide I no longer want my domain, can I get my money back?
Q:I would like to purchase my domain from App Service Domain but can I host my domain on GoDaddy instead of Azure DNS?